# Get a list of mails with attachments on Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail, google-api

So I have to build a browser extension that extracts all the emails with extensions. I am at a loss however, how to go about it. What I essentially need is for the extension to extract a list of emails with descriptions as to whether they have attachments with them. 
Now I tried the gmail atom feed
but it only shows unread emails, and doesn't give a lot of information about the message either. Is there another method of doing it.

Is there like an API for gmail that allows all this to be done easily and seemlessly. I feel like I am missing something obvious. I know i am being vague here, but I really don't have clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using IMAP doing search for "has:attachment". Samples and description  can be found under the following resource:

- [**developers.google.com - Google Apps Platform - Google Developers**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview)

Comment: what if the guy hasn't enabled IMAP on his account

Comment: I guess we just made the assumption that someone that can write a browser plugin can figure out how to switch on IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question but since this question was posted Google has released a
WEB API to work with gmail.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/